# Recursively Copy the Same File to a new Directory and Rename

Tags: recursion, copy

I have a directory structure
./DATA_150403
./DATA_150404
./DATA_150405
./DATA_150406
./DATA_150407 ...

which contains the same set of files with identical names
e.g. DATA_150403 has a LLRPT, a CVRPT, an ELRPT, a MAINREC.SDR etc.

What I would like to do is recursively copy and rename say all the LLRPT files and rename them to as LLRPT150403, LLRPT150405, LLRPT150405, etc to a new directory.

Looking for a command line or script based (Bash or VBS) solution rather than a C Perl Python Java solution.

Ideas?

Comment: Windows, Unix, or Linux?  Plus this likely belongs on Super User... http://superuser.com/

Comment: Windows (so CMD.EXE but I have Unix Utilties - grep/sed/awk etc installed). Can use Cygwin but I find it a little slow for some tasks.